# Why use explicit deny in Windows NTFS permissions

Tags: windows, ntfs, file-permissions

I'm trying to sort NTFS permissions out and what I see is that if a permission is not granted, it is implicitly denied. Thus my question is why should I explicitly deny permissions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explicit deny can be used to override inherited grant permissions without having to disable inheritance completely. It can be also used to override grants given to a whole group.